# Google API Picker failed requests and infinite cursor loading

Tags: javascript, file, picker, drive

I have implemented Google Picker API on our system, and so far have been working great. However, it has a small issue that annoys me:

During the flow of selecting a file from the widget, I noticed several failed requests on the dev tools network tab:

**Header**

[image: failed request]

**Payload**
[image: payload]

After selecting one file from the Widget, the main request seems correct but the cursor gets stuck with the loading cursor animation. As soon as I move it, the loading animation goes away, but still its a weird behaviour. If you click on the file and leave the cursor standing still the loading animation won't go until you move it.
Any idea what could be happening? I imagine it has to do with this failed request.

NOTE:
I'm using the same exact code as here, even created a project from scratch containing only this index.html and has the same issue
https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/sample

Thanks!